# How to prevent a View from rendering via a hook?

Tags: views

I want to prevent an attached view from running depending on some coding parameters.

I've tried using `hook_views_pre_view()` to prevent it from running, but I can't figure out what options to set on the view to accomplish that. Tweaking `attached` or `rendered` doesn't seem to do anything.

```
function ding_eresource_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'eresource_list' && $display_id == 'attachment_1') {
    // Prevent rendering if parent view has some option set.
    if (!empty($view->old_view[1]->barr)) {
      // This does not work. How can it be done?
      $view->attached = FALSE;
      $view->rendered = TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

How can it be done?

Comment: In my case, the view display I wanted to conditionally prevent from showing was a block display, so I was able to use hook_block_list_alter() to pick it out and remove it at that point. That way views didn't touch it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$view->executed = TRUE;` worked for me but I'm not sure it is a correct way to stop Views from rendering.

Comment: Hmm, that does work, after a fashion. Regrettably, it shows the View's empty text instead, but I worked around this by removing the empty text for the attached view.

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to do similar but just `$view->executed = TRUE;` made the query in the view still run. Looking at [`view::build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/view%3A%3Abuild/7), I understood you need the following code, to prevent anything running further in the view (displays and query).

```
$view->executed = TRUE;
$view->built = TRUE;
```

To make it clearer, the code you should use is the following one.

```
function ding_eresource_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'eresource_list' && $display_id == 'attachment_1') {
    // Prevent rendering if parent view has some option set.
    if (!empty($view->old_view[1]->barr)) {
      // This does not work. How can it be done?
      $view->executed = TRUE;
      $view->built = TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Options for `hook_views_pre_render`:

```
$view->result = array();
```

That destroys the array, preventing any data from rendering.

Or, the plain PHP option:

```
die();
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't stop pagination from rendering. I'm also assuming `die()` is a joke suggestion ;)